# Linux variant of _swab function

Tags: c, linux, endianness

Is there some analog of [_swab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e8cxb8tk.aspx) C function in Linux?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htole32.3.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer swab function in linux at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/swab.3.html

Comment: Thank you! I missed that, because i have got bad search results for "_swab".